# Dudas sobre HTML5 y Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, html5, background

Soy nuevo en esto de programar, hace dos días empecé con YouTube con el curso de 5 horas para principiantes, y ya me puse a practicar con una página web en local.

Tengo unas dudas que les pareceran bastante básicas, pero para mí son complicadas

1. Quiero separar las etiquetas  de Parrafo para cada cosa, ejemplo: hacer una división para `"Producto" <p>Este producto tiene mucho estilo<p>` y otro para `"Producto 2" <p>Este auto tiene mucho tiempo en el consesionario<p>`
2. Quiero colocar un texto abajo a la derecha y al poner `<P align="right">` se va al borde derecho, ¿ no se puede ir ajustando poco a poco ?
3. Quiero poner otro texto casi a lo ultimo de la página (hasta dónde llega la vista cuándo se entra, y el comando `<br>` me ocupa mucho espacio y además queda feo, que puedo hacer)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo completar el [tour] para conocer mejor el sitio y ganarte tu primera medalla, así como [ask] para aprender algunos trucos a la hora de escribir una pregunta. Por favor, usa texto cuando quieras compartir código, las capturas de pantalla son complicadas de leer y no se puede copiar y pegar el código que muestran a una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

No me queda muy claro lo que estás preguntando (de hecho, son varias preguntas, lo cual es causal de cierre) pero cuando se es completamente neófito en una disciplina ya es abrumador, de por sí, definir por dónde empezar a preguntar. Así que como espaldarazo y para que tu primera pregunta no caiga en saco roto, te dejo algunas observaciones. Mucho ojo con la diferencia entre un `elemento` y una `etiqueta`, que muchas veces llevan el mismo nombre pero revisten significados distintos.

- Tu HTML declara el tipo de documento (bien), luego abre el documento con etiqueta html (bien) y luego pone una metaetiqueta. Mal. El documento (o lo que es lo mismo, todo aquello contenido entre las etiquetas `<html>` de apertura y cierre) sólo puede tener como hijos los elementos `head` y `body`.  (que se delimitan por etiquetas homónimas). Tienes que declarar el elemento `head` y poner cualquier metaetiqueta dentro de éste.
- Pones una segunda etiqueta `<html>`, pero ésta no da origen a un nuevo documento. Simplemente no va ahí. Sólo quítala.
- declaras la etiqueta `<title>` justo a continuación, pero, nuevamente, ésta no puede ir directamente como hija de `<html>`, sino dentro de `<head>`.
- Declaras una etiqueta `<center>`, la cual

  - no puede ser descendiente directo del documento, debe ser descendiente directo o indirecto del elemento `body`
  - por lo anterior, no puede ser paralela a un elemento `title`
  - está obsoleta y no se recomienda su uso. A cambio se utiliza `<div style="text-align:center">` (por ejemplo)
- Abres el elemento body con la etiqueta `<body>`, la cual

  - no puede tener elementos paralelos más que el elemento `head`
  - no tiene una propiedad `background`, sino que se utilizaría `
  - quedó sin `chevron` de cierre  (>)

De ahí para adelante, formalmente todo lo demás en tu HTML no está dentro del *elemento* body sino dentro de la *etiqueta* body.

```
    <body background="background.jpg"

        <p>esto no tiene sentido</p>

     >
```

versus

```
     <body style="background:url('background.jpg')">

        <p>esto sí</p>

     <body>
```

En líneas generales: el browser siempre hará el mejor esfuerzo por reparar un HTML mal formado, pero el resultado probablemente no se verá como uno espera. El algoritmo para cerrar etiquetas mal cerradas y omitir etiquetas imposibles es resiliente pero no mágico. En resumen, antes de pelear con los estilos, comprueba la estructura.

Answer (score 0):

html5 se usa para darle estructura a la pagina, pero los estilos a cada elemento se los podes colocar directamente en la etiqueta, pero es recomendable que aplicques Css. las propiedades de css que te pueden servir para colocar los elementos a medida son los siguientes:

- padding
- margin
- position